# (Django) Order by desc

Tags: python, django

I can not order my News table. I guess i did everything right but django shows me error! Please check my code maybe something went wrong

```
class News(models.Model):
news_title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
news_text = models.TextField(max_length=1000)
news_logo = models.ImageField(upload_to='uimages')
created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

class Meta:
    verbose_name = 'News'
    verbose_name_plural = 'News'
    **News.objects.filter().order_by('-created_at')**
```

Comment: what is the error?

Comment: NameError: name 'News' is not defined

Comment: If you're looking to change the default ordering of the default object manager, then look [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/options/#ordering)

Comment: What does this line do in Meta class? `**News.objects.filter().order_by('-created_at')**`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are some indentation problems in your code, or at least in the example you posted. The code snippet should be indented as follows:

```
class News(models.Model):
    news_title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    news_text = models.TextField(max_length=1000)
    news_logo = models.ImageField(upload_to='uimages')
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'News'
        verbose_name_plural = 'News'
```

Specifically, the `Meta` class needs to be part of the `News` class.

In terms of changing the default ordering, as in some of the comments already pointed out, the correct way to do this is to use the `ordering` attribute inside the `Meta` class. If you always want to order by `created_at` in descending order, you'd need to define the classes as following:

```
class News(models.Model):
    news_title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    news_text = models.TextField(max_length=1000)
    news_logo = models.ImageField(upload_to='uimages')
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'News'
        verbose_name_plural = 'News'
        ordering = ['-created_at']
```

You can find more information about model options in the [Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/options/).

Comment: Thank you! I am just new in Django so i have that mistakes

Comment: No problem at all, happy to help. This is how all of us learn :)

Answer (score 1):

Why are you putting that query in the Meta class? It sounds like you want to achieve a [default order as shown in this Django doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/options/#ordering). In which case, you don't put a query there, you just set the order property:

```
class Meta:
    verbose_name = 'News'
    verbose_name_plural = 'News'
    # this line:
    ordering = ['-created_at']
```